# M4 eval precision

Tags: css, math, floating-point, m4

I'm trying to use M4 macros to generate css files. I'm willing to enter my values in px and do simple math using eval() to get results in em. Unfortunatly I didn't find how to get floats.

```
define(`FONTSIZE', `13')dnl
define(`LINEHEIGHT', `17')dnl
.content {padding : eval(LINEHEIGHT / FONTSIZE)em}
>>> m4 style.css.m4
>>> .content {padding : 1em}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that floating point arithmetic is not supported in M4. The fixed-point solution proposed in the answer is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular purpose the expression may become something like

```
eval(LINEHEIGHT/FONTSIZE).substr(eval(((LINEHEIGHT%FONTSIZE)*1000)/FONTSIZE + 1000),1)
```

(of course, use the power of 10 that meets your precision requirements)
This is a common trick to obtain a floating point-like result from a division. Other operators are more complicated, not to say the functions like sin, cos, ln...

In general it would be possible in principle to write some floating point manipulation macros implemented with string manipulations and integer operators, but I think it's more pratical to use an external program (bc, gawk...) invoked by "syscmd()" when the operations are not as simple as a division.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from previous answer:

```
define(`FONTSIZE', `13')dnl
define(`LINEHEIGHT', `17')dnl

.content {padding:syscmd(bc <<< "scale=6; print LINEHEIGHT/FONTSIZE")em;}
```

NB: `scale=6;` is for floating precision

NB: I've written a little macro for this, you can find it here: [m4 preprocessor BC macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249104/m4-preprocessor-bc-macro/24261282#24261282)