# m4 preprocessor BC macro

Tags: m4

Relative to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442861/m4-eval-precision/24248299#24248299), I'd like to define a `BC` m4 macro of that function:

```
syscmd(bc <<< "scale=6; print ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_STRING")
```

NB: It just process an arithmetic operation with `bc`, for ex: `syscmd(bc <<< "scale=6; print 1.2*2") => 2.4`

I guess something like:

```
define(`BC', syscmd(bc <<< "scale=6; print $1"))
```

but how to **expand other variables in BC argument**, eg:

```
define(`ONEPOINTTWO', `1.2')
define(`TWO', `2')

BC(ONEPOINTTWO*TWO)
=> 2.4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define(`BC', `syscmd(echo "scale=6; print $1" | bc)')
```

then:

```
BC(ONEPOINTTWO*TWO)
=> 2.4
```